# Several post types on WP Query by tag and taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, taxonomy

On my taxonomy page I have to display several post types (album, filmes, reviews, video and post) on the same list, with different designs for each. I can display the posts easily, but when I try to pull publications from other post types I won't get shit-emoji. Can someone help? Please and thank you

[image: please and thank you]

```
<?php $temp_query = clone $wp_query; ?>
<?php
    $term = $wp_query->queried_object; $tag = $term->slug;     
    query_posts("showposts=18&post_type=post&artistas=$tag&tag=$tag");     
?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        a lot here 
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $wp_query = clone $temp_query; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: You need to add them to post_type, don't know how to do it via query string parameters, with array parameters it's easier.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this code looks really bad, but let's try to clean it a little bit and make it work...

First of all, there is no need to all that mess with cloning queries. It makes no sense, to be honest. `wp_reset_query()` will recreate all query based on request, so there is no point in assigning anything to this variable. Also it would be a lot nicer and efficient, if you use your own custom `WP_Query` instance and not `query_posts`. Andthe last but not the least... It's more readable and efficient if you pass args as an array and not as a string...

Saying that your code could look something like this:

```
<?php
    $term = get_queried_object();
    $tag = $term->slug;
    $artists = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page' => 18,
        'post_type' => array('post', 'your-other-cpt1', ...),
        'artistas' => $tag,
        'tag' => $tag
    ) );
?>
    <?php if ( $artists->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $artists->have_posts() ) : $artists->the_post(); ?>
        a lot here 
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // there's no need to reset wp_query, since it hasn't been modified now ?>
```

PS. The only problem I can still see in here is that you query posts that belongs to 2 different taxonomies and has the same term slug in both of these taxonomies. It doesn't look right to me, but maybe that's the case on your site... :)